# Trying to create view inside a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

I am unaware and do not know how to resolve this: I am trying to create view in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. It is showing an "incorrect syntax" error, help me solve this, thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Active_products 
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE VIEW Active_Product 
    AS
      SELECT 
          m20.Series_Code AS Series_Code,
          COUNT(m20.Material_Desc) AS Count_of_Active_Products 
      FROM
          material_master m20
      WHERE
          m20.Material_Desc NOT LIKE '%BLK%' 
          OR m20.Material_Desc NOT LIKE '%BLOCKED%' 
          OR m20.Material_Desc NOT LIKE '%BLOCK%'
      GROUP BY 
          m20.Series_Code;

    CREATE VIEW actv_products  
    AS 
        SELECT 
            Series_Code, 
            SUM(Count_of_Active_Products) AS Count_of_Active_Products 
        FROM
            active_product
        GROUP BY 
            Series_Code;
```

Comment: You cannot create a view inside a stored procedure.  This question shows the user has not done even basic research regarding whether this is even possible or allowed in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why you need to do this, but you can do it using `sp_executesql`. For example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('CreateSomeObjects') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP PROCEDURE CreateSomeObjects
END;

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateSomeObjects
AS
BEGIN;

    EXEC sp_executesql N' 
    IF OBJECT_ID(''view01'') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN;
        DROP VIEW view01;
    END;'

    EXEC sp_executesql N' 
    CREATE VIEW view01
    AS
    SELECT 1 AS [TEST]'



END;

GO 

EXEC CreateSomeObjects

GO

SELECT *
FROM view01;
```

Note, that I have added a check to drop the view, if it already exists.